# Setup with InstallShield LE shows warning about Unknown Publisher

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015, installshield, installshield-le

I have developed a Desktop tool using C# Winforms, in Visual Studio 2015. For this tool I have generated a Setup using InstallShield LE.

When a customer downloads this setup file from my website and runs the setup, the customer gets the warning thath the Publisher is unknown:
[image: Open File - Security Warning]

In the InstallShield General Information section I do have a Publisher specified, so I do not understand why the customer gets this warning.

Does anybody have an idea?

Thanks,
Danny

Comment: Look this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6868772/how-to-set-the-publisher-name-for-a-windows-forms-application

Comment: Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the note at the bottom of the dialog box:

> This file does not have a valid digital signature that verifies its publisher. You should only run software from publishers you trust. How can I decide what software to run?

When your setup is not signed (or is signed with a certificate whose authenticity cannot be verified), you will see prompts similar to the one you show. Fix this by signing it with a certificate that will be trusted in the target environment (such as an Authenticode code signing certificate purchased from a trusted authority).